# Python - Using 'With Module as x' and Threading.Timer

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, ocr

I'm trying to use [Tesserocr](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr) to continuously read a changing line of text, as frequently as possible (right now that is every 3 seconds, but I want it to be much more frequently).

Right now, I have the following code:

```
 from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI

 def readingFunction():
     threading.Timer(1.0, readingFunction).start()
     with PyTessBaseAPI() as api:
          # Get image
          img = getImageForOCR()

          # Get OCR Text
          api.SetImage(img)
          return api.GetUTF8Text()

 readingFunction()
```

This works well, but every time the function runs, PyTessBaseAPI() loads and that slows down my code. If I get the 'with PyTesBaseAPI()..' statement outside the function like this:

```
 from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI


 with PyTessBaseAPI() as api:
     def readingFunction():
          threading.Timer(3.0, readingFunction).start()

          # Get image
          img = getImageForOCR()

          # Get OCR Text                  
          api.SetImage(img)
          return api.GetUTF8Text()

     readingFunction()
```

.. then it works well only the first time, but then the second time (and the next runs fired by the Timer), I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1182, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
File "TestFile.py", line 111, in <module>
    def readingFunction():
File "TestFile.py", line 118, in returnOCRTextFrom
    return api.GetUTF8Text()
File "tesserocr.pyx", line 2111, in tesserocr.PyTessBaseAPI.GetUTF8Text
RuntimeError: Failed to recognize. No image set?
```

I have tested, and `img` does have a valid image, and I believe `api.SetImage(img)` is run.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?